# cakephp3 find data with selected columns

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

Hi I'm trying to find data in Cakephp3

What I'm doing is I'd like to find data with selected columns which are product name, product code, and small image url.

```
$contain = [
    'Image' => [
            'ImageFile'
        ]
    ];

$products = $this->Product->find()
        ->contain($contain)
        ->select(['Product.name', 'Product.product_code', 'Product.Image.ImageFile.small_image_url'])
        ->where(['Product.name Like' => '%'.$keyword.'%']);
```

However, I got an error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Product.Image.ImageFile.small_image_url' in 'field list'
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the column name is small_image_url

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,Can you please tell us what is structure of DB?

Secondly, There is a way to debug query in cake3 by debug kit. Please let us know what query is generating for:

```
$products = $this->Product->find()
        ->contain($contain)
        ->select(['Product.name', 'Product.product_code', 'Product.Image.ImageFile.small_image_url'])
        ->where(['Product.name Like' => '%'.$keyword.'%']);
```

**Please Try this query and let me know what is output in debug kit:**

```
$contain=[
    ['Image' => function($q) {
        return $q->autoFields(true);
    },
    'ImageFile'=> function($q) {
        return $q->autoFields(true);
    }
    ],
];
$products = $this->Product->find()
                 ->contain($contain)
                 ->autoFields(true)          
                 ->where(['Product.name Like' => '%'.$keyword.'%']);
```

Comment: The query generated is SELECT Product.name AS `Product__name`, Product.product_code AS `Product__product_code`, Image.ImageFile.murl AS `Image__ImageFile` FROM product Product LEFT JOIN image Image ON Image.image_id = (Product.main_image_id) WHERE Product.name like :c0 ORDER BY Product.name ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Comment: Also the structure for product is Product table has a HasMany relation with Image table and the Image table has HasMany relation with ImageFile table. But somehow when I generate the query without select, in Product object under ImageFile it starts with array like ImageFile => [ 0 => [ image_id => 1234, image_location => '/var/www/~~~']]; something like this. And I can select columns on product table and image table but not on imagefile table.